# Error while remount a partition read only

Tags: shell, android

I have a rooted HTC and need to create a custom file in /system/xbin. I execute a mount command (for read-write permission on /system), create the file, remount /system in readonly and after that my file magically disappear.
Here are the commands I wrote in a su shell via dab.

```
root@m7:/system/xbin # mount | grep system
/dev/block/mmcblk0p35 /system ext4 ro,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0

root@m7:/system/xbin # mount -o rw,remount /dev/block/mmcblk0p35 /system
root@m7:/system/xbin # cd /system/xbin

root@m7:/system/xbin # echo test > myfile
root@m7:/system/xbin # ls
daemonsu
dexdump
dexus
myfile <- 'myfile' is created
nc
su


root@m7:/system/xbin # cat myfile
test

root@m7:/system/xbin # mount -o ro,remount /dev/block/mmcblk0p35 /system
root@m7:/system/xbin # ls
daemonsu
dexdump
dexus
nc
su
```

*PUFF* after remounted /system in readonly my file is disappeared.
Any idea about this?

EDIT 1: If I try to re-execute the commands, my HTC restarts itself ...
EDIT 2: As you could see in the 'ls' command output, in /system/xbin exist 'su' installed with a root tool. How could this root tool install 'su' permanently?